# Combinatorial proof for summation of powers of two

Tags: summation, exponentiation

I apologise if this has been posted before, but I've been poring over this problem for days now and just can't seem to get it.

I'm looking for a combinatorial proof for:

$2^n - 1 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 +...+ 2^{n-1}$

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Hint: $a^n-b^n=?$

Comment: Hint: Think about two different ways of counting all proper subsets of a set of $n$ elements.

Comment: @Martigan he needs a combinatorial proof...

Comment: @gt6989b My bad... I should have taken a better look at the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We count the non-empty subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$. There are $2^n-1$ of them.

There are $2^0$ subsets with biggest element $1$, $2^1$ with biggest element $2$, $2^2$ with biggest element $3$, and so on up to $2^{n-1}$ with biggest element $n$. Add up.

Comment: Oh! Ohhh. Oh. Thank you so very much! I can finally start practicing with other questions :D

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

**Tools**

- [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) 
  For $\displaystyle k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}} ~: ~2^k = (1 + 1)^k = \sum_{r=0}^k  \binom{k}{r}$.
- [Hockey Stick Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) 
  For $\displaystyle k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~r \in \{0,1,\cdots, k\}, ~: ~\sum_{i=r}^k  \binom{i}{r} = \binom{k+1}{r+1}$.

---

Using the Binomial Theorem:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left[\sum_{r=0}^k \binom{k}{r}\right]$.

The above double summation may be represented by the following two dimensional table, where each inner summation is represented by a specific row.

\begin{array}{l l l l l l }
  \binom{0}{0} \\
  \binom{1}{0} & \binom{1}{1} \\                     
  \binom{2}{0} & \binom{2}{1} & \binom{2}{2} \\  
  \binom{3}{0} & \binom{3}{1} & \binom{3}{2} & \binom{3}{3} \\
  \cdots \\
  \binom{n-1}{0} & \binom{n-1}{1} & \binom{n-1}{2} & \binom{n-1}{3} & \cdots \binom{n-1}{n-1}\\
\end{array}

The above table may be alternatively expressed as a double summation, where each inner summation is represented by a specific column.

$\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \left[\sum_{i=r}^{n-1}\binom{i}{r}\right]$.

Using the Hockey Stick Identity, this equals :

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{r+1} = \sum_{r=1}^n \binom{n}{r}.\tag1 $$

Re-applying the Binomial Theorem against the RHS of (1) above, it may be re-expressed as

$\displaystyle \left[\sum_{r=0}^n \binom{n}{r}\right] - \binom{n}{0} = 2^n - \binom{n}{0} = 2^n - 1.$