# Give a combinatorial proof for the expression $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^n - 1$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to come up with a combinatorial proof for the given expression:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^n - 1$

I know the algebraic method to prove the given expression, where I simply substitute the values into the expression for the sum of a GP with n terms. I was trying to come up with a combinatorial proof for the same but couldn't solve it. I considered the RHS as the total number of bit strings of length n except the string with all 0's. However, I can't see how to count the same on LHS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Every nonempty subset of $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$ has one and only one largest element.

Comment: or equivalently, each bit string of length $n$ (other than the one with all 0s) has a bit that equals 1 and all the following bits are 0.

Comment: Okay I understand. So if I fix the position of the rightmost 1 in the string to the bit position, say k, then all the remaining k-1 positions have 2 choices, while all the bit positions to the right of k have 0's. Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty much it, and if you $0$-index the bit string, then when you select the bit in position $k$ (for $0\leq k \leq n-1$), then there will be $k$ free bits to its left, so the $k$ directly corresponds to the $k$ appearing in $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$.

Comment: You find the full combinatorial proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329073/combinatorial-proof-for-summation-of-powers-of-two. Is there a way to mark questions as duplicate?

Comment: @EldarSultanow  To mark a question as a duplicate, click on Close (at the bottom of the post), select Duplicate, then select the duplicate target (the question you found), then click on the button Vote to Close.

Comment: @user2661923  I do not know the answer to that question.  My suggestion is that you ask whether an answer to a question marked as a duplicate should be transferred to the original question on [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Per moderator advice on meta math, I deleted my answer to this question, and transplanted it as an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329073/combinatorial-proof-for-summation-of-powers-of-two/4261685#4261685),